# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue

Tags: java, jvm, jit

My Java application fails after it worked couple of days during JIT compilation.
May be native memory is defragmented, but its only 8Kb was needed...
I have over 700 threads. 2Gbs of heap (only 1Gb was used when jvm failed)
Please, help to solve this.

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 8192 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_solaris.cpp:2677), pid=25465, tid=47
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_31-b13) (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.31-b07 mixed mode solaris-sparc compressed oops)
# Core dump written. Default location: /location/core or core.25465
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000100c75000):  JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread3" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=47, stack(0xffffffff58d00000,0xffffffff58e00000)]

Stack: [0xffffffff58d00000,0xffffffff58e00000],  sp=0xffffffff58dfcfd0,  free space=1011k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0xddc994]  void VMError::report_and_die()+0x6e4
V  [libjvm.so+0x5347d4]  void report_vm_out_of_memory(const char*,int,unsigned long,VMErrorType,const char*)+0x64
V  [libjvm.so+0xb7304c]  int os::Solaris::commit_memory_impl(char*,unsigned long,bool)+0x10c
V  [libjvm.so+0xb73334]  bool os::pd_commit_memory(char*,unsigned long,unsigned long,bool)+0x2c
V  [libjvm.so+0xb66354]  bool os::commit_memory(char*,unsigned long,unsigned long,bool)+0x2c
V  [libjvm.so+0xdd756c]  bool VirtualSpace::expand_by(unsigned long,bool)+0x150
V  [libjvm.so+0x684364]  bool CodeHeap::expand_by(unsigned long)+0xc8
V  [libjvm.so+0x492038]  CodeBlob*CodeCache::allocate(int,bool)+0xa0
V  [libjvm.so+0xb1e08c]  nmethod*nmethod::new_nmethod(methodHandle,int,int,CodeOffsets*,int,DebugInformationRecorder*,Dependencies*,CodeBuffer*,int,OopMapSet*,ExceptionHandlerTable*,ImplicitExceptionTable*,AbstractCompiler*,int)+0x2d0
V  [libjvm.so+0x3ec93c]  void ciEnv::register_method(ciMethod*,int,CodeOffsets*,int,CodeBuffer*,int,OopMapSet*,ExceptionHandlerTable*,ImplicitExceptionTable*,AbstractCompiler*,int,bool,bool,RTMState)+0x524
V  [libjvm.so+0x4b6c90]  Compile::Compile(ciEnv*,C2Compiler*,ciMethod*,int,bool,bool,bool)+0x1380
V  [libjvm.so+0x3b4898]  void C2Compiler::compile_method(ciEnv*,ciMethod*,int)+0xa8
V  [libjvm.so+0x4d02b8]  void CompileBroker::invoke_compiler_on_method(CompileTask*)+0xeb0
V  [libjvm.so+0x4cebf8]  void CompileBroker::compiler_thread_loop()+0x490
V  [libjvm.so+0xd2611c]  void JavaThread::thread_main_inner()+0x94
V  [libjvm.so+0xd26068]  void JavaThread::run()+0x398
V  [libjvm.so+0xb6dcb0]  java_start+0x390
C  [libc.so.1+0xe2464]  _lwp_start+0x8
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tomcat crash: There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122402/tomcat-crash-there-is-insufficient-memory-for-the-java-runtime-environment-to-c)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about solaris, but linux has the sysctl `vm.max_map_count` that limits the maximum number of virtual memory *mappings*.

So while there may be enough free physical ram and virtual address space it might run out of the number of allowed mappings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the operating system reported it was out of virtual memory.  I would look at how much free swap space you have and consider increasing it.

One way to give the system more free swap space is to *reduce* the heap size if you are not using it all.

Note: GB = Giga Bytes, Gb = Giga-bits.

Comment: OS:                          Oracle Solaris 11 11/11 SPARC
  Copyright (c) 1983, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
                            Assembled 18 October 2011

uname:SunOS 5.11 11.0 sun4v
  (T2 libthread)
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE infinity, NOFILE 65536, AS infinity
load average:11.03 11.16 10.38

CPU:total 32 v9, popc, vis1, vis2, blk_init, sun4v, niagara_plus

Memory: 8k page, physical 16646144k(3133616k free)

Comment: Look like there was enough memmory at that moment - 3133616k free in hs_err_pid25465.log

Comment: Swap space is 2gbytes

Comment: @MarkVilkel in any case "Out of Memory Error" is reported by the operating system, the usage of the heap is not a factor. It could be that you are hitting a resource limit for the process instead.  what do you see for `ulimit -a`?

Comment: core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited 
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited 
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited 
open files                      (-n) 256 
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 10 
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192 
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited 
max user processes              (-u) 29995 
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited